# Exception in java with NullPointerException how to do it without throw?

Tags: java, exception

What is the programming implementation of `NullPointerException` in java. Having a book which describe `NullPointerException` ,and done using first throw it using `throw` statement. But how to implement this exception in simple try catch block without using throw.

like we can throw `ArithmetcException` by doing `throw new ArithmetricException()`
or to generate the exception we do in

```
try { 
  a=b/0;
} catch(ArithmeticException x);
```

Like the above,  how to generate `NullPointerException` without explicitly throwing it?

Comment: String s =null; s.length();

Comment: Why? What's the point? What's the *"...[specific programming problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)..."* you're running into where you need to do this?

Comment: When ever you try to access any instance methods in a null object, you will get NullPointerException. So try accessing any null objects and boom, there you are.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
Object obj = null;
obj.equals(this);
```

Will cause an `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

Any method call performed on any `null` object reference would cause `NullPointerException`.

```
String s = null;
s.toString();
```

Comment: I literally typed this exact thing out (same variable name too).

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc that's the first thing that sprang to my mind :)

Comment: +1 Also, you should add an explanation why this causes it a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily throw **NullPointerException** , just use this code

```
try{
  String nullString = null;
  nullString.isEmpty();
catch(NullPointerException nex){
  System.out.println("NullPointerException:"+nex);
}
```

The exception will be thrown because you are trying to call **isEmpty()** method on a null object.